# Difference between service and application in a service oriented architecture?

Tags: web-services, dropwizard

When i came across learning about service oriented architecture i felt what is the difference between a service and application ? Any valuable suggestion really helpful .

Answer (score 0):

a quick google query: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/soa/services-applications.html

Essentially, a service is something rather specific. An application can provide one or multiple services, but a service usually fulfills one purpose specifically.

So, in terms of dropwizard, you can use it for both. You can create a DW application that provides multiple services via e.g. HTTP. Or you can use it to build stand-alone micro services: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices

I hope that gets you started.

Artur

Comment: Thanks. It really helpful.

Comment: @Sivagurunathan.v  No worries - here's some other read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I came upon it during my research while developing my own OS. After encountering so many ambiguous definitions and articles on the subject, including that presented by @pandaadb, the only thing that became clear is the difference between services vs applications is quite blurry. So, drilling down on my own SOA where I defined clear boundaries between components, the distinction should be simply viewed as such:

***Services are used by applications; applications are used by users.***

Now, you might be thinking that, say, a font picker service has a GUI for user access so it is, therefore, an application. *Not so fast!* A font picker's only purpose is allow the user to pick a font for...? Right. A font picker holds no direct purpose for the user, only indirect, i.e. it provides font services for applications where the user needs to select fonts. So, services provide specific capabilities to applications while also providing a GUI, if needed, to manage said capabilities.